# What is an example UDP server timeout?

Tags: udp, ip

[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol):

> Datagrams – Packets are sent individually and are checked for
>   integrity only if they arrive. Packets have definite boundaries which
>   are honored upon receipt, meaning a read operation at the receiver
>   socket will yield an entire message as it was originally sent.

If a datagram can be split into multiple packets, it seems that there must be some timeout that the IP or UDP layer use to discard packets if not all packets for a datagram are received.

Is there a timeout? What is an example timeout?

Comment: It happens at the IP layer, and it would be a function of the TTL of the packet.

Comment: @EJP TTL makes sense. But I don’t see how the IP layer knows to buffer multiple IP packets before sending them up to UDP.

Comment: It 'knows' because reassembling fragmented IP packets is one of its functions.